# Assets Library not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I am using a photo gallery feature in the app I am building, so users can take pictures from within the app and it will save them to a custom album, with special metadata attached to identify which pictures belong to the app.

After saving the picture, I attempt to reload my table displaying what it found, and it never finds the most recently added picture.  Only after I leave the view, and bring it up again does it find the most recent picture.

I use [this](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/) category to save to the custom album.  Here's a couple excerpts from my code showing the saving/loading process

Saving

```
NSMutableDictionary *realMetaData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[realMetaData setObject:metaData forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary];
[library saveImage:imageToSave toAlbum:albumName metadata:realMetaData withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    if ( error != nil )
    {
        NSLog(@"Error saving picture? %@", error);
    }
    [self loadAlbum];
}];
```

Loading

```
-(void) loadAlbum
{
    [library groupNamed:albumName withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, ALAssetsGroup *foundGroup) {
        if ( error == nil )
        {
            self.album = foundGroup;
            [self loadAssets];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error loading album: %@", error);
        }
    }];

}

-(void) loadAssets
{
//  self.assets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:album.numberOfAssets];
    for ( id key in [events allKeys] )
    {
        NSArray *event = [events objectForKey:key];
        if ( event != nil && event.count > 0 )
        {
            [events removeObjectForKey:key];
        }
    }
    [album enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if ( result != nil )
        {
            NSDictionary *metaData = result.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
//          NSLog(@"Retrieved image metadata: %@", metaData);
            NSDictionary *tiffData = [metaData objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary];
            NSString *encodedData = [tiffData objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyTIFFImageDescription];

            if ( encodedData != nil )
            {
                NSArray *parts = [encodedData componentsSeparatedByString:@"##"];
                if ( parts.count == 3 )
                {
                        NSLog(@"Found picture named %@", [parts objectAtIndex:2]);
                        NSString *eventName = [parts objectAtIndex:1];
                        NSArray *foundEvent = [events objectForKey:eventName];
                        if ( foundEvent != nil )
                        {
                            NSMutableArray *mutableEvent = [foundEvent mutableCopy];
                            [mutableEvent addObject:result];
                            [events setObject:mutableEvent forKey:eventName];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            NSMutableArray *newEvent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                            [newEvent addObject:result];
                            [events setObject:newEvent forKey:eventName];
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }];
}
```

Everything decodes with the metadata correctly, just the one image that I JUST added to the library does not show up.

Comment: @mablecable Not yet, if you find a solution, I'd definitely be interested to hear it